# How to develop a histogram in Tableau from agregated data?

Tags: aggregate, histogram, tableau-desktop

I have a raw data set on student performance for a particular test. The data is on the question level, and contains student name, question category, question, points earned, points possible. I want to aggregate the students' final scores, and then place those scores into histogram bins. I seem to only be able to either bin the question level scores into a histogram or aggregate student performance totals, but not both. How could I do that?

My data looks something like this:

StudentA, Cat_A, Question_A, 3 , 5

StudentA, Cat_A, Question_B, 1 , 5

StudentA, Cat_B, Question_C, 2, 2

StudentB, Cat_A, Question_A, 5, 5

StudentB, Cat_A, Question_B, 3 , 5

StudentB, Cat_B, Question_C, 2, 2

StudentC, Cat_A, Question_A, 1, 5

StudentC, Cat_A, Question_B, 5 , 5

StudentC, Cat_B, Question_C, 0, 2

Comment: The Tableau feature that will most likely help with this task is the LOD calc. So start by reading about LOD calcs in the on-line help, Tableau blogs and watching training videos. LODs have several use cases, but are good fits when you have a multi-step process that works at different levels of detail, such as first aggregating student scores for tests, and then working with those scores as input to your histogram view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned, you can use a Level of Detail Calculation to solve this issue. The LoD would look something like this:

{FIXED [student], [category],[question]: SUM([points])}